# Semantic UI / Fomantic UI form validation with Google reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: forms, validation, recaptcha, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm trying to find a way to validate Semantic UI / Fomantic UI forms using Google reCAPTCHA v3. I found an option for validation using Google reCAPTCHA v2 here on Stack. But, the new form of V3 validation is different and uses another form of user interface.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** I found a way. I used this source as an initial reference: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/example-of-how-to-add-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form--cms-33752. Follow the form of validation using Semantic UI / Fomantic UI. On the other hand, to validate the data on the server, follow the previous reference for more information.

Validation of the form:

```js
var formSelector = 'formSelector'; // Form selector

$('.ui.form')
    .form({
        onSuccess(event, fields){
            var action = 'action'; // Action 
            var googleSiteKey = 'googleSiteKey'; // Google Site Key 
            
            grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                grecaptcha.execute(googleSiteKey, {action: action}).then(function(token) {
                    $(formSelector).append('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'+token+'">');
                    $(formSelector).append('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="'+action+'">');
                    $(formSelector).unbind('submit').submit();
                });
            });
            
            return false;
        }
    });
```